# Can I filter on decoded UTF-8/Base64 in Thunderbird?

Tags: utf-8, base64, thunderbird

This is not my area at all so please excuse any mistakes in terminology or misunderstandings about what is/isn't possible!

I've recently started getting about 100 spam emails a day where the body is entirely UTF-8/base64 encoded. The Subject is plain text, the body is UTF-8/Base64 and the headers have this in common (no other common field like sender, etc. I could use):

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

I don't see any way to filter against Content-Type or Content-Transfer-Encoding but I don't want to indiscriminately filter out all UTF-8/Base64 emails anyway (or do I? Is that in itself enough to identify undesirable email?) - is there a way to filter in Thunderbird based on the text that is displayed when the UTF-8/Base64 is decoded? I've tried filtering on character strings I see in the body when I save the email as a file, e.g. this appears at the start of the body all of these emails:

```
PCFkb2N0eXBlIGh0bWw+DQo8aHRtbCB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS94aHRt
```

but that sometimes is and sometimes isn't found by Thunderbird when filtering on the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all email is UTF-8 encoded (all 7-bit ASCII is also UTF-8). Looking at this, it seems the unusual thing is it's been Base64 encoded. Usually this would be `quoted-printable` or `7bit` in my experience, so that may be a worthwhile thing to filter on. You may be able to at least flag anything with `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` as suspicious (though in my own mailboxes, I do see recent legitimate base64-encoded mails, so they're not unprecedented).

Depending on your experience writing JavaScript, you should be able to write a solution using [FiltaQuilla](http://www.mesquilla.net/mesquillacom/extensions/filtaquilla/). In particular, you could decode the base64 into quoted-printable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Base64 being the real problem. I've never written JavaScript and to be honest REALLY don't want to have to learn it just for this. I might filter all the base64 emails to a separate folder for now but I'm hoping there's a definitive way to just search the text for a string and delete the email if present like I do with some other filters. I have to believe I'm not the only one with this issue so there's got to be a simple solution already out there.

Comment: I wouldn't bet there was a simple solution yet. Spammers often come up with new approaches that sneak past the existing systems, and it can take quite a while before a solution is common. I just played whack-a-mole with a spammer who sent me stuff every day that got past all my filters. I built some hacky things to slow it down, and then suddenly it stopped entirely (not due to any change I made). I expect the spam filters are already decoding Base64; I suspect that there's something funny about the characters inside the Base64.

Comment: OK, thanks. For now I've set up a filter following the directions at https://superuser.com/a/180742 (but Content-Type and Content-Transfer-Encoding as 2 separate items with "Match all of the following" selected) and moving matching emails to Spam. I'll just keep an eye on that for now. If I don't get a more robust answer in the next few hours I'll come back and accept yours later today. Thanks.